# Create custom menu item in Object Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, ssms, ssms-addin

**Basic question is how to create custom menu items in Object Explorer in Sql Server Management Studio ?**

[image]

Actually what I want to implement is create menu item which will perform as:

1. Create CRUD stored procedures for the table on which the user had done right-click.
2. Possibly other stuff like remove duplicate records.

The executing module could be external written in C#.NET

I have checked [SSMS Addins](http://ssmsaddins.codeplex.com/) but I think it is different than what I am looking for.. (please correct me if I am wrong)

I hope I am clear enough now ! [image: :D]

Comment: Its not hard to do using a SSMS Addin, there is some help out there but not much because SSMS-Addins are not supported by Microsoft.  The implementation is slightly different for each version of SSMS - this is the key starting place. (Dont confuse the version of SSMS with the version of the database engine you connecting to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some links to get you started :

[Create SSMS Addin](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2008/07/28/how-to-create-sql-server-management-studio-addin.aspx)

[Extend Functionality in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio with Add-ins](http://www.jasinskionline.com/TechnicalWiki/Extend-Functionality-In-SQL-Server-2005-Management-Studio-With-Add-ins.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Some Gotchas for SQL 2008 R2

[SQL 2008 R2 Breaks SSMS Addins](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/sql-server-2012-extended-events-add-in-to-manage-2008r2-instances/)