# SQL Server insertion performance

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, clustered-index, insert-statement, database-fragmentation

Let's suppose I have the following table with a clustered index on a column (say, a)

```
CREATE TABLE Tmp
(
    a int,
    constraint pk_a primary key clustered (a)
)
```

Then, let's assume that I have two sets of a very large number of rows to insert to the table.

- 1st set) values are sequentially increasing (i.e., {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,..., 999999997, 999999998, 99999999})
- 2nd set) values are sequentially decreasing (i.e., {99999999,999999998,999999997, ..., 3,2,1,0}

do you think there would be performance difference between inserting values in the first set and the second set? If so, why?

thanks

Comment: For large numbers of rows the plan would probably have a sort operation to ensure that the rows were presented in clustered index order anyway. If the inserts were to be in the order presented the second one would probably end up with much more logical fragmentation. [Example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9382500/73226)

Comment: // womp: not a homework question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server will generally try and sort large inserts into clustered index order prior to insert anyway.

If the source for the insert is a table variable however then it will not take account of the cardinality unless the statement is recompiled after the table variable is populated. Without this it will assume the insert will only be one row.

The below script demonstrates three possible scenarios.

1. The insert source is already exactly in correct order.
2. The insert source is exactly in reversed order.
3. The insert source is exactly in reversed order but `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is used so SQL Server compiles a plan suited for inserting 1,000,000 rows.

#### Execution Plans

[image: Plans]

The third one has a sort operator to get the inserted values into clustered index order first.

```
/*Create three separate identical tables*/
CREATE TABLE Tmp1(a int primary key clustered (a))
CREATE TABLE Tmp2(a int primary key clustered (a))
CREATE TABLE Tmp3(a int primary key clustered (a))

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;

GO

DECLARE @Source TABLE (N INT PRIMARY KEY (N ASC))

INSERT INTO @Source
SELECT TOP (1000000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) 
FROM sys.all_columns c1, sys.all_columns c2, sys.all_columns c3

SET STATISTICS TIME ON;

PRINT 'Tmp1'
INSERT INTO Tmp1
SELECT TOP (1000000) N
FROM @Source
ORDER BY N

PRINT 'Tmp2'
INSERT INTO Tmp2
SELECT  TOP (1000000) 1000000 - N
FROM @Source
ORDER BY N

PRINT 'Tmp3'
INSERT INTO Tmp3
SELECT 1000000 - N
FROM @Source
ORDER BY N
OPTION (RECOMPILE)

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
```

#### Verify Results and clean up

```
SELECT object_name(object_id) AS name, 
       page_count, 
       avg_fragmentation_in_percent, 
       fragment_count, 
       avg_fragment_size_in_pages
FROM 
sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(), object_id('Tmp1'), 1, NULL, 'DETAILED') 
WHERE  index_level = 0 
UNION ALL 
SELECT object_name(object_id) AS name, 
       page_count, 
       avg_fragmentation_in_percent, 
       fragment_count, 
       avg_fragment_size_in_pages
FROM 
sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(), object_id('Tmp2'), 1, NULL, 'DETAILED') 
WHERE  index_level = 0 
UNION ALL 
SELECT object_name(object_id) AS name, 
       page_count, 
       avg_fragmentation_in_percent, 
       fragment_count, 
       avg_fragment_size_in_pages
FROM 
sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(), object_id('Tmp3'), 1, NULL, 'DETAILED') 
WHERE  index_level = 0 

DROP TABLE Tmp1, Tmp2, Tmp3
```

#### `STATISTICS TIME ON` results

```
+------+----------+--------------+
|      | CPU Time | Elapsed Time |
+------+----------+--------------+
| Tmp1 | 6718 ms  | 6775 ms      |
| Tmp2 | 7469 ms  | 7240 ms      |
| Tmp3 | 7813 ms  | 9318 ms      |
+------+----------+--------------+
```

#### Fragmentation Results

```
+------+------------+------------------------------+----------------+----------------------------+
| name | page_count | avg_fragmentation_in_percent | fragment_count | avg_fragment_size_in_pages |
+------+------------+------------------------------+----------------+----------------------------+
| Tmp1 |       3345 | 0.448430493                  |             17 | 196.7647059                |
| Tmp2 |       3345 | 99.97010463                  |           3345 | 1                          |
| Tmp3 |       3345 | 0.418535127                  |             16 | 209.0625                   |
+------+------------+------------------------------+----------------+----------------------------+
```

#### Conclusion

In this case all three of them ended up using exactly the same number of pages. However `Tmp2` is 99.97% fragmented compared with only 0.4% for the other two. The insert to `Tmp3` took the longest as this required an additional sort step first but this one time cost needs to be set against the benefit to future scans against the table of minimal fragmentation.

The reason why `Tmp2` is so heavily fragmented can be seen from the below query

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT TOP 3000 file_id, page_id, a
FROM Tmp2
CROSS APPLY sys.fn_PhysLocCracker(%%physloc%%)
ORDER BY a
)
SELECT file_id, page_id, MIN(a), MAX(a)
FROM T 
group by file_id, page_id
ORDER BY MIN(a)
```

With zero logical fragmentation the page with the next highest key value would be the next highest page in the file but the pages are exactly in the opposite order of what they are supposed to be.

```
+---------+---------+--------+--------+
| file_id | page_id | Min(a) | Max(a) |
+---------+---------+--------+--------+
|       1 |   26827 |      0 |    143 |
|       1 |   26826 |    144 |    442 |
|       1 |   26825 |    443 |    741 |
|       1 |   26824 |    742 |   1040 |
|       1 |   26823 |   1041 |   1339 |
|       1 |   26822 |   1340 |   1638 |
|       1 |   26821 |   1639 |   1937 |
|       1 |   26820 |   1938 |   2236 |
|       1 |   26819 |   2237 |   2535 |
|       1 |   26818 |   2536 |   2834 |
|       1 |   26817 |   2835 |   2999 |
+---------+---------+--------+--------+
```

The rows arrived in descending order so for example values 2834 to 2536 were put into page 26818 then a new page was allocated for 2535 but this was page 26819 rather than page 26817.

One possible reason why the insert to `Tmp2` took longer than `Tmp1` is because as the rows are being inserted in exactly reverse order on the page every insert to `Tmp2` means the slot array on the page needs to be rewritten with all previous entries moved up to make room for the new arrival.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, you only need to look up  what effect clustering has on data and the manner in which it is logically ordered. By clustering ascending, higher numbers get added on to the end of the table; inserts will be very fast. When inserting in reverse, it will be inserted in between two other records (read up on page splitting); this will result in slower inserts. This actually has other negative effects as well (read up on fill factor).

Comment: Inserting in exactly reverse order doesn't mean there will be any more page splits. Just every new page allocated is in the wrong place.

Comment: I thought it only split pages if it had to. So filling it (to the fill factor) in order would fill each page before adding a new one. Whereas inserting would (likely) case a page split.

Comment: FillFactor only makes any difference when you rebuild an index not for inserts. In the OP's case the first page would get filled up with (say) rows 99999999 to 999999900 then it needs to insert 999999899 that goes on a new page then 999999898, 999999897 etc can just go on that new page as they are not interleaved with the data already inserted and so on. All of the pages are likely to end up out of order though impacting future scans.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with allocating pages sequentially as is done for a clustered index.  With the first they would naturally cluster together.  But in the second, I think you would have to keep moving the page locations to have them sequentially ascending.  However, I really only understand SQL server at a conceptual level, so you'd have to test.