# Does the sort order of Index effects the fetching time of a record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table that stored blog information and the information is identified by a column `bId`.

Such like if the first blog had a `bId` 1 the latest blog after 10 posts will have `bId` 10.
However, this information can be accessed from anywhere as any post can be visited. But as a general understanding latest post will be visited more often than the older ones.

Which means there are more chances of fetching of information with `bId` 10 rather than 1.

So If I create an index over this `blog` table’s column `bId` does it matter in my above case if I declare the `index` `ASC` or `DESC` or it will be same?

And which one will be more appropriate in my case: `CREATE INDEX [IDX_bId] ON [blog] ([bId] ASC);` or `CREATE INDEX [IDX_bId] ON [blog] ([bId] DESC);`?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743858/sql-server-indexes-ascending-or-descending-what-difference-does-it-make, which is possibly a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short not really. The index on the column will provide the most important information. The optimiser will then decide how best to retrieve your rows. If you have a composite index then it may have an impact.

Answer (score 1):

First you probably want to create that index as CLUSTERED. A clustered index defines the order for the actual data rows; it's essentially the order of the table itself. If you do not define a clustered index at all you table is a 'heap' meaning that pages are stored in no particular order on disk.

To answer your question: if the only access pattern will be by ID, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM blog
WHERE bId = 10
```

than it doesn't matter if your index is defined as ASC or DESC.

However for a query like this:

```
SELECT TOP (100) * 
FROM blog
ORDER BY bID DESC
```

the clustered index should be defined as bID DESC. The reason for this is that if the index is ASC, then this query will need to perform a backward scan, and backward scans cannot use parallelism (as explained here: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/descending-indexes). If your table is large, this may impact the performance.