# Are table indexes reversible?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, database-indexes

If I have a simple table:

```
ArticleName (string)
CategoryID (int)
LastModified (datetime)
```

And I create an index:

```
CategoryID (ASC)
LastModified (ASC)
```

For the query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CategoryID = 1 ORDER BY LastModified ASC
```

Would I need a separate index for ordering by `LastModified DESC`?

Comment: Not necessarily, but that would help to avoid SORT operator in execution plan. Usually they're costing quite a lot.

Comment: a good read - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743858/sql-server-indexes-ascending-or-descending-what-difference-does-it-make)

Answer (score 3):

No, not in SQL Server, and not in most DBMS that use B*tree indexes. This type of index can be traversed just as efficiently forwards as backwards, because the leaf nodes are joined into a double-linked list.