# Slow performance: select order DESC when index is ASC

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, database-performance

I'm struggling with a query that runs fast when ORDER BY is ASC but not when it's DESC.

Pseudo code:

```
TABLE Logs (
   Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
   Time DateTime,
   AccountId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
   Deleted BIT,
   /* Other columns */
)
```

Because this is a multi-tenant system, Logs are inserted with Time ascending most of time and queries are with Time descending most of the time, I also have:

```
CLUSTER INDEX 
FOR TABLE Logs
(Deleted ASC, AccountId ASC, Time ASC)
```

The problem is now with the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM Logs
WHERE Deleted = 0
AND   AccountId = 'id-of-an-account'
ORDER BY Time DESC
```

That query is slow (17 secs), but if I change to `ORDER BY Time ASC` it runs in <1seg.

I've been reading I think I can change the `CLUSTER INDEX` to be `DESC` on `Time`.  However, [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9382500/72350), that can create a lot of fragmentation.  I could also create another non-clustered index, but that would impact the inserts performance.

Running SQL Server 2008 R2.  Any idea?  Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

The query is actually slow because of a combination of what I've mentioned and that I have an INNER JOIN, the actual query is something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM Logs l
INNER JOIN Other o
    ON o.Id = l.Id
WHERE Deleted = 0
AND   AccountId = 'id-of-an-account'
ORDER BY Time DESC
```

I believe that the INNER JOIN is not letting the query use the index.

Comment: Adding a non-clustered index just on [Time] DESC would have a negligible impact on INSERT performance.   Have you looked at the Execution plan to verify that the CI is being used in the slow query?

Comment: @TabAlleman yes, it's funny that the execution plan does not even change (at least I didn't find any differences) and the estimated time is the same (50% if I put both queries).  The index you suggested is fine but it would need to be on Deleted, AccountId, Time I believe.

Comment: if you're using SSMS, just include the actual execution plan and it will normally tell you if an index will increase the performance